# Convergence at the radius of convergence

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Suppose I have (roughly speaking) a multivalued meromorphic function $f(z)$ on all of $\mathbb{C}$ that is single-valued and holomorphic on the open unit disc and has some branch points of finite order (but no poles) on the unit circle.  Does the Taylor series always converge uniformly to $f(z)$ on the closed unit disc?  This seems very likely but I do not think I have ever seen a proof.

I know an argument that works for the simplest possible case, namely the function $f(z)=\sqrt{1-z}$.

Comment: The point is that it is not clear whether the Taylor series at $0$ of $f$ is even convergent on any point of the boundary. Or is it?

Comment: Wouldn't uniform convergence on your disk imply that your function admits its derivative at the branch point? (By a "switch-sum-and-differentiation"-type argument.. Or am I wrong?)

Comment: @Alexandre: how does this follow from Abel's theorem?  That tells us that if we have a point $u$ on the unit circle and the Taylor series converges at $u$, then the Taylor series converges uniformly on the line segment $[0,u]$.  It is not obvious that the hypothesis is satisfied, and even if it is, the conclusion is weaker than uniform convergence on the whole closed disk.

Comment: @Tommaso: I don't think we can switch the sum and the derivative here.  The usual argument for that involves a contour integral, and the contour would have to wind around the branch point, which would break the proof.

Comment: @Alexandre: my question was about the converse statement indeed. It is a Tauberian-type result. It is true if $a_n=O(1/n)$ if you write $f(z)=\sum\n a_n z^n$. But is this the case in the situation? And this alone cannot guarantee the convergence is uniform.

Comment: Assume $f$ has only finitely many branch points in a neighborhood of the circle Have you tried to bound the modulus of the coefficients $a_n$ of the Taylor series at $0$ by integrating on a path contour which lies mostly outside the closed unit disc (say, on a circle of radius $1+\vareps$), except near the branch points where the contour passes through it. Maybe this way you can show that $a_n$ is $O(1/n)$ and apply Tauber's result. Or maybe you can even devise a direct proof of the uniform convergence this wày. Only a passing idea, though…